# Checking if the JavaScript File has already been downloaded

Tags: javascript, download

If the same Javascript file has different URL's then is it possible to find out that if the JavaScript file has already been downloaded. Not using the URL but using the name of the file.

Is this possible using JavaScript?

Comment: http://danml.com/js/filename2.js

Comment: Why not set a global variable that indicates that the file has been downloaded, and check that?

Answer (score 1):

If you defined a variable in the script, you can check if the variable is already defined:

```
if (typeof(myScriptDefined) == "undefined") {
    myScriptDefined=true;
    // rest of my script content
}
```

Comment: I would prefix `window.` to that just to make it explicit that yes, you DO want a global variable in this case

Answer (score 0):

You could find all `<script>` elements in the DOM and check if any `src` attributes match the regex of the filename.